# php Import Excel sheet to mysql cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, mysql, excel, cakephp, import

I will have millions of records in my `Excel sheet` provided by client, and I am finding a better ready made component or helper in `CakePHP 1.3` version to `import excel sheet to MySQL` database records.

Please let me know earliest response with better solution.

Comment: Millions of records?!? That's a significantly large document: What format of Excel is it? How many worksheets? None of the suggested libraries are going to work well if the spreadsheet really is as large as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [PHP-Excel-Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

For that you have to add excel reader library in your Vendor folder like this vendors\php-excel-reader and yourdatafile.xls should be under webroot folder

```
function index(){
App::import('Vendor', 'php-excel-reader/excel_reader2');
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader('yourdatafile.xls', true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent found a Plugin for CakePHP which does extensive work.

But you can use [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) as vendors and just import it into the controller and go ahead and do everything.

Answer (score 0):

try using [it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

It works fine for me. Hope it helps u too