# load external class and member function in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2.

I want to import data in bulk from excel file and save them to database. For this I'm using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop) Library.

I have downloaded the library and extracted in `vendor` directory and thus the filepath to `PHPExcel.php` is

```
/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php
```

and filepath to `IOFactory.php` is

```
/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php
```

I'm including this in my controller like

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

include '../vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include '../vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/**
 * Products Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ProductsTable $Products
 */
class ProductsController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        if ($this->Auth->user()['status'] != 1) {
            $this->Auth->deny(['sell']);
        }
        $this->Auth->allow(['bulkUpload']);
    }

    public function bulkUpload()
    {
       $inputFileName = $this->request->data('excel_data');


       if ($inputFileName != '') {
         $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName); // line 33
         $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

         $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
         $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
         $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
         $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

         for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $this->data['Program']['cycle_month'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
            $this->data['Program']['cycle_year'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
            $this->data['Program']['media_partnum'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();

            $resultArray[$row-2] = $this->data['Program'];
        }

            debug($resultArray);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note : I have never used such plugin and bulk upload that is why I followed code from This Question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406298/phpexcel-plugin-does-not-import-file-in-cakephp)*

**Now, the problem is, When I select a file and upload, it gives error as**

```
 Class 'App\Controller\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found at line 33
```

I think the problem is with calling `PHPExcel_IOFactory` class.

`PHPExcel_IOFactory` class is inside `IOFactory.php` file

```
<?php

/**    PHPExcel root directory */
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . 'PHPExcel/Autoloader.php');
}

class PHPExcel_IOFactory
{
    /**
     * Search locations
     *
     * @var    array
     * @access    private
     * @static
     */
    private static $searchLocations = array(
        array( 'type' => 'IWriter', 'path' => 'PHPExcel/Writer/{0}.php', 'class' => 'PHPExcel_Writer_{0}' ),
        array( 'type' => 'IReader', 'path' => 'PHPExcel/Reader/{0}.php', 'class' => 'PHPExcel_Reader_{0}' )
    );

    /**
     * Autoresolve classes
     *
     * @var    array
     * @access    private
     * @static
     */
    private static $autoResolveClasses = array(
        'Excel2007',
        'Excel5',
        'Excel2003XML',
        'OOCalc',
        'SYLK',
        'Gnumeric',
        'HTML',
        'CSV',
    );

    /**
     *    Private constructor for PHPExcel_IOFactory
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
    }
    public static function identify($pFilename)
    {
       $reader = self::createReaderForFile($pFilename);
       $className = get_class($reader);
       $classType = explode('_', $className);
       unset($reader);
       return array_pop($classType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel unable to read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098569/phpexcel-unable-to-read-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it's a simple problem of namespaces. Just put a slash before the name class as it is in the global namespace

```
$inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
```

Comment: I think in your case, you have moved files from `Classes` to `PHPExcel` directory.

Comment: Is the code on line 33 is correct ? because I'm still getting `Class 'App\Controller\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found on line 33`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but not giving error `File not found`. I have created a separate question for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098569/phpexcel-unable-to-read-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use composer to load PHPExcel library. It will auto include all classes in your project.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Cheers :)