# PHPExcel unable to read file

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-3.2, phpexcelreader

I'm using CakePHP 3.2 and `PHPExcel` library to import data from excel sheet to database.

I have the library at

```
/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php
/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php
```

and the action in controller is

```
public function bulkUpload()
{
   $inputFileName = $this->request->data('excel_data');
   //debug($inputFileName['name']);
   if ($inputFileName != '') {
     $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
     $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

     $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
     $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
     $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
     $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

     for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        $this->data['Program']['cycle_month'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
        $this->data['Program']['cycle_year'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
        $this->data['Program']['media_partnum'] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();

        $resultArray[$row-2] = $this->data['Program'];
     }

      debug($resultArray);
  }
}
```

**But this gives error as**

```
pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, 
array given [ROOT/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php, line 225]
```

and

```
file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, 
array given [ROOT/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php, line 72]
```

and on `debug($inputFileName);` it gives

```
[
    'name' => 'testing.xlsx',
    'type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpvDWDxG',
    'error' => (int) 0,
    'size' => (int) 5247
]
```

**replacing `$inputFileName;` with `$inputFileName['name']` in**

```
$inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
```

removes above two error but gives error as

```
 Could not open testing.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.
```

*Here, `testing.xlsx` is the file I'm selecting from form*

Comment: That's because you've uploaded the file, but haven't yet used `move_uploaded_file()` so it's still only a temp file; you should be using `$inputFileName['tmp_name']`

Comment: I used `tmp_name` too but still same error. Haven't tried `move_uploaded_file()` . But what it has to do with saving files on server. Can't it be done directly ?

Comment: [move_uploaded_file()](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: what do you mean with 'still same error', what exactly did you try of Mark's comment?

Comment: @arilia @mark said "you should be using $inputFileName['tmp_name]" . I already have tried this with error as `expects parameter 1 to be string`

Comment: and this is strange since `$inputFileName['tmp_name]` **is** a string. You have two occurence of `inputFileName`, did you replaced both with `$inputFileName['tmp_name]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to add file like below:

require_once(ROOT. DS .'vendor'.DS.'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS.'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

y0ou also need to add a namespace like below

use PHPExcel;
use IOFactory;

Now you can access excel class library and easily read and write
```

i am using this in my project.

you can try.

Thanks :)